# A riddle in the jungle

Tags: riddle

> I had lived with the monkeys,
> I may fart like the skunks,
> I can sing like a nightingale,
> I eat like a tiger.
>
> I can ruin or save the world,
> As how the jungle gods did.
> I can build a shelter like a beaver,
> What do you think I am?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Wild guess but are you mankind/humans?

I had lived with the monkeys,

> We evolved from certain primates.

I may fart like the skunks,

> Humans can fart and fart stinky one.

I can sing like a nightingale,

> Some humans can sing well.

I eat like a tiger.

> A lot of humans eat meat.

I can ruin or save the world as how the jungle gods did.,

> Humans have to power to change the environment for the good or bad like no other animal

I can build a shelter like a beaver,

> I think this is obvious

Comment: Lol what a guess!

Comment: Wow, the answer is so obvious that one might think it's something else.